# Multi images, cannot get first image from array

Tags: gatsby, strapi

I have a gatsby app which is connected to a Strapi backend.
On my homepage i want to display all projects and their first image from the gallery.

My query looks like this:

```
        allStrapiProject {
          edges {
            node {
              title
              gallery{
                localFile{
                  publicURL
                  childImageSharp {
                    gatsbyImageData(
                      placeholder: BLURRED
                      formats: [AUTO, WEBP, AVIF]
                      layout: FULL_WIDTH
                    )
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
```

my index.js looks like this

```
    <Layout>
      <div id="projects" className="featured-grid">
        {data.allStrapiProject.edges.map(({node: project}) => {
          const image = getImage(project.gallery[0].localFile);
          return (
            <div>
              <p>{project.title}</p>
              <GatsbyImage image={image} />
            </div>
          )
        })}
      </div>
    </Layout>
```

and i get this error

```
Error in function eval in ./src/pages/index.js:18
Cannot read properties of null (reading '0')
```

seems like its not letting me get the first value from the array.
also when i do console.log(project.gallery) i can see all the arrays, but when i try to console.log(project.gallery[0]) i get the same error.

Any ideas ?

Edit*
console.log(project.gallery)

[image]

Comment: Can you add the `console.log(project.gallery)`?

Comment: I have added the output. It seems ok, but when i try to get the first item's public url `{project.gallery[0].localFile.publicURL}` i get Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading '0')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resolution has been:

```
{
  project.category.name === "Photo" && (
    <GatsbyImage
      image={getImage(project.gallery[0].localFile)}
      alt="asdasdasd"
      className=""
    />
  );
}
```

The problem was that some categories don't contain `gallery` node so the approach should only apply to `Photo`

Comment: I just found where the problem was. Projects have a category ( photo, video ) - projects from video category have gallery = null. I've done like this and now is working: `{project.category.name === "Photo" && (
          <GatsbyImage
            image={getImage(project.gallery[0].localFile)}
            alt="asdasdasd"
            className=""
          />
        )}`

Comment: Thanks! I've updated the answer for those who might help